# Google app engine launcher "No selected projects are running so we have nothing to browse"

Tags: google-app-engine

Google app engine launcher is not working and I receive this message whenever I try to deploy: an existing app, create new or even deploy the demo one; "No selected projects are running so we have nothing to browse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  Google App Engine Launcher has been deprecated (you can confirm it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/5esgvujAqIQ)). It is strongly recommended to switch to the Cloud SDK to continue working with GAE.